# Python: Refresh local folder

Tags: python-3.x, refresh, box

I have a program that accesses a local BOX folder which should be synced with BOX Web before execution. The local BOX folder will be synced by default whenever there is a change in the BOX Web. But sometimes, the local folder doesn't get sync with Web unless we give a **manual refresh**.

**Question**: Is there a way to refresh the local folder using Python? So that I can refresh and start the program.

Answer (score 0):

use `os.stat()`, it will give updated status of folder